# CFLocation opening in a new window instead of the CFDIV (in Firefox Only)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfform

I have a `cfform` inside of a `cfdiv` where people can register for my site.  When the form submits, it processes everything and if there is any reason to send the user back to the registration form, a `cflocation` is triggered.

It is supposed to redirect back to the `cfdiv`, not a new page. That is one of the reasons the `cfdiv` tag is useful.  It works just fine in Internet Explorer. But in Firefox it opens the `cflocation` page in the parent window instead of the `cfdiv`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use cflocation for this.

You should cfoutput a block of `<script>` that invokes this JS function: `ColdFusion.navigate`

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fd0.html

Comment: You definitely can.  That's one of the plusses of cfdiv,cfwindow, etc.  I found what was happening.  I had a cfabort in the processing page so the rest of the code couldn't execute.  Once I took the cfabort out it redirected correctly.  This one is closed.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed.  A lot of cf tags are smarter than I give them credit for.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Had a cfabort on the processing page.  Took it out and now its working as expected.  And yes, cflocation can be used inside a cfdiv without the parent window refreshing.

Comment: So does cflocation change behaviour and output some JS code when inside a cfdiv block? :/ If so, how would one override it to work as standard? Is this documented anywhere? (It's not mentioned on the [cflocation man page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cac.html).)

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not entirely sure.  I often wondered if cflocation was just a shortcut for meta refresh (0 seconds).  I do think the cfform elements do output some JS though.  So if you don't have those setup correctly you'll get a JS error when the div processes.

Comment: cflocation does a 302 redirect instead of meta refresh. :) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cac.html